# How to run the cron job as a user instead of root user

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have few bash scripts which are adding to cron jobs with specified timing, but it needs to be executed as root user. I am trying to run those scripts i.e., crob jobs but it needs root user permission, since I am running this jobs in ubuntu ec2 instance where root user is restricted. What would be the work around to run those scripts as root user.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question. Perhaps `super` or `sudo` commands could help you?

Comment: This belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Comment: You've been around long enough to know this doesn't belong here.  If you want to know how to cron a bash script on linux under a different user account, try [unix.se].  If EC2 plays a significant part in this, try [sf].

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/173924/how-to-run-a-cron-job-using-the-sudo-command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

1) add the script(s) to the crontab of root. To do this you have to do `sudo su -` or `su -` to become root, then add the cron jobs by using `crontab -e`

2) allow a non-root user to use a crontab, and add the cron job to that user's crontab , by using `crontab -e`
  **and** set the set-uid flag of your script and change ownership to root, so it will execute as root `chmod +s scriptname; chown root scriptname`

Answer (score 10):

You can make a script execute as root by using the [setuid flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid), which makes a script run as its owner:

```
chmod +s yourscript
chown root yourscript
```

Just make `yourscript` run whatever command you want to run as root.

Note that with this method, any user can run the script.

Comment: Many platforms will ignore `setuid` on script files for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Basile is right with his comment. If you want to run something as `root` in Ubuntu, use `sudo`.

If you want to execute a script (or some commands) automatically with superuser rights without having to type in a password, run

```
sudo visudo
```

to edit the [sudoers](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) file. To make `sudo` stop asking for a password for a specific script (or command) insert

```
username ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
```

where `username` is the name of the user calling sudo.