# Auto-backup shell github

Tags: github, backup, cron-task

I wrote a script to auto-backup a website and this script will push resources to **github**. I wrote some code in **crontab** to let it auto-execution. However, I don't know why resources can't be pushed.

I can see the heads from `.git` that it has been modified (which means commit successfully). I guess the problem is that the incorrect use of username.

The information below is the output of auto-backup script.

```
Committer: root &lt;root@xxxx.(none)>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:    
    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com    
After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:    
    git commit --amend --reset-author    
 1 file changed, 14 insertions(+), 14 deletions(-)
```

How can I deal with it?

The command in crontab:

```
*/2 * * * * root /var/backWiki.sh >/home/xxx/Tmp/4.txt
```

Here is the main part of this shell script:

```
git pull originTyl master
git add -A
echo '2'
git commit -a -m $nowtime
echo '1'
git push originTyl master
echo '3'
```

origninTyl means:

```
`[remote "originTyl"]`
`url = https://accoutName:password@github.com/xxxx/xxxx.git`
`fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/originTyl/*`
```

Comment: What is the script (or the general gist)?  Also, do you have a public key in github associated with root on your computer?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with cron, but I would guess one way might be to wrap this with `su` to change you to the correct user.

Answer (score 0):

You should first test that script under your own account, where `git config user.name` and `user.email` must be set properly.

Then you should register your script top `cron`, making sure it is [executed as you, not as `root`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178545/how-to-run-the-cron-job-as-a-user-instead-of-root-user), [each user having his/her own `crontab`](http://insanelabs.com/linux/linux-crontab-notes-for-different-users-run-a-cron-job-every-time-a-system-reboots/).

> Run `cron` jobs as a different user:

```
su - <user> -c <command or script>
```

---

The [OP Yulong Tian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714449/yulong-tian) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514357/auto-backup-shell-github/16516684?noredirect=1#comment23757720_16516684):

> I have solved my problem by changing the user (not `root` as before) in crontab.

Comment: Thank you. I have solved my problem by changing the user(not root as pervious) in crontab.

Comment: @YulongTian Ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.