# Custom Django management command not running with crontab

Tags: python, django, django-admin, cron

I have an app in a django website that looks like in the tutorial of this page [django_documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) and it runs very well if I run the command:

```
python manage.py closepoll.py
```

After I installed Crontab and I put it in INSTALLED APPS in settings.py file. Also I put this line in my settings.py file:

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/5 * * * *', 'django.core.management.call_command', ['closepoll']),
]
```

To be able to run the script every 5 minutes. I add the cronjob through:

```
python manage.py crontab add
```

And it was added perfectly. After I restart the server but nothing is happening every 5 minutes. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this package. What did it actually add to the crontab?

Comment: How do you know nothing is happening? Also, what is the crontab entry that was created?

Comment: @DanielRoseman This package what allows you is to run a cron job from your settings.py file

Comment: Yes I understand that, but what cron job did it actually create?

Comment: I know that nothing is happening because the script should add rows to the database table and it's not doing it

Comment: @DanielRoseman the script which is inside the app directory

Comment: Argh. Please post the generated contents of your crontab.

Comment: @DanielRoseman `root@mycomputer:/home/django/django_project# python manage.py crontab add
  adding cronjob: (ba71c777ea2f98004073d19d0773aed6) -> ('*/5 * * * *', 'django.core.management.call_command', ['script'])`

Comment: @Albert - are you sure the role who runs the django server has the access right to alter your crontab? As output from above comment, it seems you run the command as root so crontab can be updated?

Comment: @Anzel You are right, I'm the root. What do I need to do to check what you said?

Comment: @Albert - first of all, you need to check which "user" is running your django server upon server restart?

Comment: @Anzel, how can I check that? Sorry but I'm new to run servers

Comment: @Albert - hmm... are you on Ubuntu? Do you use systemd or anything to run your django server? Or supervisor??

Comment: @Anzel I'm on Ubuntu. I create a droplet in DigitalOcean with Django already setup. That helps?

Comment: @Albert - I'm not too familiar to django in DO, but I check DO site that the server will be run as "django" user. So can you check what group "django" user belongs to? You can do `cat /etc/sudoers` and see if it has root privileges

Comment: This is what is showing the cat (1st part):`#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults env_reset
Defaults mail_badpass
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"`

Comment: @Anzel This is the second part:
`# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d`

Comment: @Albert - crontab can be run by root privileges. and clearly "django" hasn't got that rights, that's why your management command isn't run. To resolve this, one solution is to add "django" user in sudoer, by running command `visudo`, then add `django ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` under `root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` line. WARNING: granting web server user role with root access is NOT ENCOURAGED and is considered weak security... I will STRONGLY suggest you don't use the django crontab and just manually ADD an entry in crontab instead.

Comment: or look at this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178545/how-to-run-the-cron-job-as-a-user-instead-of-root-user) for running cron jobs for non-root users, however IMHO it just makes things more complicated.

Comment: @Anzel so what I would have to do instead of giving django the rights? How I can add manually the entry in crontab?

Comment: whatever your django management command adds to your crontab, you can just manually add/paste to crontab as root with `crontab -e` while you're root. I'm not sure will DO persists the changes but I will suggest doing so instead

Comment: @Albert - that's great and I hope you have this solved. In case your question no longer belongs to programming, you can post related question in [server fault](https://serverfault.com/), there are plenty of experts who can help you with a better solution.