# How to run a script hourly that requires password?

Tags: bash, sudo, gnu-screen

I want to call a script every hour which I was doing by using following commands:

```
Step 1. Connect to your cloud desktop using ssh.
Step 2. Run these commands:
% screen
% while true; do ./parseScript.sh; sleep 3600; done
Step 3. Close the window with the running command.
Step 4. (same as Step 1) Connect to your cloud desktop using ssh.
Step 5. Run this command: screen -R. You will get back to the session you left in step 3.
```

Now the problem is that in my script I have 1 command which has to be executed using sudo hence this will ask for password every time, Is there anyway to run this script every hour except manually?

Comment: You can configure your account to not require a password to sudo.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178545/how-to-run-the-cron-job-as-a-user-instead-of-root-user ?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure sudo to do not require password for a certain combination of user and command.

For instance, if the username that needs to run the command is `keshav` and the command is at `/sbin/someCommand`:

First create a copy of your sudoers file, just in case

```
sudo cp /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.backup
```

Then edit the /etc/sudoers

```
sudo visudo
```

That command will open the `/etc/sudoers` file in your default editor. Use the editor to add this line

```
keshav ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/someCommand
```

Save the file and exit the editor.

If you followed the steps correctly your user `keshav` should now be able to run `sudo /sbin/someCommand` without a password prompt

Comment: I am working on cloud desktop and trying to execute ./parseScript.sh which has following command: sudo -u identmon /apollo/env/PARISOperationalTools/scripts/get/callRetryOfFailures.rb "$apiname" "$requestinput"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expect` command. Example code

```
#!/bin/bash
spawn scp $p testuser@192.168.2.2:/home/testuser
expect "Password"
send "Pass@123\r"
```

Comment: can you explain it in more details?

Comment: You can check out this link https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/  Expect script will send the response without any user interaction.